# iOS interface declaration based on #if evaluation

Tags: iphone, ios, interface, superclass, conditional-compilation

I need a way to conditionally define the superclass of a class based on a value in NSUserDefaults.

I know one can define different interfaces based on #ifdef directive. I wonder if the same can be achieved with #if directive?
If not, is there some other way to achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with a preprocessor directive, since it would be determined at compile time while NSUserDefaults is something you want to check at runtime.

I think this thread could help you [Dynamically change an object's superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060629/dynamically-change-an-objects-superclass)
Anyway, are you sure this is the best you can do by design? Why would you change the superclass at runtime based on something in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I currently have two different implementations for the same thing. Each one uses a different inheritance. I want the user to be able to switch between the two and persist this choice among launches....

Comment: Still I'm not sure if this is a good pattern. Usually different inheritances mean completely different things, while different subclasses of a specific class mean "something is added to this class, something is maybe overridden". Have you considered using protocols or categories instead of different inheritances?

Comment: Yes, two different classes is not an option, because this class is accessed from many places in the app, and if there are two of them, I will have to call the appropriate one in all those places.

Comment: You can easily overcome this if you access this classes by handling their protocols and not their actual implementations