# Overriding the parent of a class with a subclass

Tags: ios, class, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am looking for an efficient way to override the parent class of a UITableViewController. The parent class of UITableViewController is UIViewController. I have a subclass of UIViewController which is called **SpecialViewController**. I would like to make a subclass of UITableViewController called **SpecialTableViewController**. How can I achieve this?

```
UIViewController -> SpecialViewController -> UITableViewController -> SpecialTableViewController
```

Or am I breaking some rules?

Comment: Possible only in runtime, but think twice before you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its possible at compiletime. But its possible at runtime. Take a look here: [Dynamically change an object's superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060629/dynamically-change-an-objects-superclass)

Comment: I'd rather not hack together a solution at runtime. I'll have to look for another solution. Thanks for the help