# UIView's drawRect not being called when swizzled

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect, swizzling

I am experimenting with advanced Objective-C methods. What I want to achieve is to append specific drawing code to an existing `UIView`.

I started easily, I went on to declare my own `drawRect` method in a category:

```
@interface UIView (Swizzled)

- (void)my_drawRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

Then I swizzled the `drawRect` method of `UIView` in the implementation of the category:

```
+ (void)load
{
    [self swizzleInstanceMethod:@selector(drawRect:) withMethod:@selector(my_drawRect:) inClass:[UIView class]];
}

- (void)my_drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog (@"Test.");
}
```

**Implementation of this method is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Legoless/Haystack/blob/master/SDK/NSObject+Swizzle/NSObject+Swizzle.m) and the swizzling works in all other cases.**

So according to the logic, every time `drawRect` is called, it should just print out "Test". But it does not work, the method I swizzled is never called. I went on to discover what I did wrong here, but the more I look at it, the more I believe the problem is somewhere else.

What if the `drawRect` method is not even called? I went on to try to force it being called:

```
view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Doesn't work either.

So my question is:

**How to force `UIView` to call `drawRect` in this case or even my swizzled implementation?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for `swizzleInstanceMethod:withMethod:inClass:]`?

Comment: The code for this method is available at: [GitHub](https://github.com/Legoless/Haystack/blob/master/SDK/NSObject+Swizzle/NSObject+Swizzle.m), like written in the post above. It is irrelevant to this question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, read [to drawRect or not to drawRect (when should one use drawRect/Core Graphics vs subviews/images and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659563/to-drawrect-or-not-to-drawrect-when-should-one-use-drawrect-core-graphics-vs-su)

Basically, `UIView` checks if you override `drawRect:` or not. If you don't override it, it can do lots of drawing optimizations and the method won't be even called.

In this case you didn't override it so `UIView` sees no reason to call it, even if you replaced the empty implementation with something else.

Comment: This is a great illustration of the dangers of runtime reflection and metaprogramming. You use the runtime to change something, which doesn't have the expected behaviour because it breaks assumptions that someone else made when writing code that uses the runtime. A more vicious example of this is isa-swizzling an object that KVO also swizzles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221110/my-isa-swizzling-breaks-kvo

Comment: Great resources, both of you. I'm assuming that `UIView` does more deep checks if `drawRect` is implemented and probably there is no way to force this.